# Center Logo in ul?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I know many people have tried to do this, and worked out some system that just happened to work out, or just to "get by", but what is the best way to do this? I have something almost complete, but for some reason the logo is not centered, rather the whole ul as a whole. This is what i get.

[image]

But, this is what i get when the text length is the same:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="navbar">

    <ul>

        <li>
            <a class="navbarLinks" href="#">Big Text Here</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a class="navbarLogo" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" width="100"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a class="navbarLinks" href="#">Small Text</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="divider"></div>

</div>
```

And my css:

```
.navbar
{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.navbar li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbarLinks
{
    color:#ccc;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;  
    text-shadow: -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px #000;
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbarLinks:hover
{
    color:#fff;
}

.navbarLogo
{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How do i fix my code?

Comment: [solved by flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/), if you don't mind ditching IE 9 and below.

Comment: I do need those. Is there a css way?

Comment: flexbox is css  :)  just pretty recent.

Comment: Can u link me with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, albeit a giant hack, is to just give the left and right `<li>`s a percentage `width` of, say, 40% or so.  Then they'll stay the same size while leaving a bit of a gap for the logo in the middle.

The best way is to use a flexbox, which lets you explicitly say what you want, i.e. to split any extra space between the two text parts:

```
.navbar ul {
    display: flex;
}
.navbar li.navbarLinks {
    flex: 1;
}
```

This just says: the `ul` should be a flexbox (meaning all its children should sit in a row and fill the available space), and any extra space should be given to the links at a ratio of 1:1.

Here's a [crappy fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PXGc/).

The downside is that this only works in [pretty recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), and in particular IE10 was the first IE to support it.  *And* there have been three revisions to the syntax, so you'd need to support those as well, perhaps with something like this [Sass flex mixin](https://github.com/mastastealth/sass-flex-mixin) (which is a useful reference even if you're writing static CSS).

On the other hand, you could use *both* approaches.  Browsers that don't understand flexbox would obey the `inline-block` instead and just see a slightly off-center logo.

Comment: That is one way, but I want it to be a non hack